# Swift SpriteKit sprite moves but retains original position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Using the normal Game app setup with integrated gameplay kit.  In scene did load I added

```
  self.hero = SKShapeNode.init(rectOf: CGSize.init(width: 10, height: 10), cornerRadius: 1)
    if let hero = self.hero {
        let pos = CGPoint.init(x: -50, y: -90)
        hero.lineWidth = 5
        hero.position = pos
    }

    self.addChild(self.hero!)
```

Then in the update function I added

```
 if let hero = self.hero {
        let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(x: 12, duration: 1)
        hero.run(moveAction)
    }
```

This runs fine and the sprite moves as desired, but there appears to be a copy of the sprite in the original position.  What am I missing. Surely it doesn't need to be removed and added on every update

Comment: How can you access the variable hero inside another function, did you make it global? Please show **all** relevant code

Comment: you should add more code - specially where the line `self.addChild(self.hero!)` is called. maybe this codeline ist called many times and you have just duplicates (similar to common error with the reused TabelViewCell where people add every time it is reused a new Control)

Comment: I think that I would work just by removing the unnecessary `let hero = self.hero` inside the update funtion, that probably causes your app to recreate hero every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happened because you should use (as the *"hello world"* Sprite-kit game template syntax):

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {}
```

instead of :

```
override func sceneDidLoad() {}
```

Seems that `sceneDidLoad` is fired twice, xCode sets up a dummy version of the scene first, then the real scene. There is also a [bug](https://openradar.appspot.com/29090190) opened about it.

Your code **output**:

[image]

**Output** with `didMove(to view:`:

[image]

---

About your comment take a look at this image (it come from Xcode version 8.2.1 - new project - game template (spritekit):

[image]

Comment: This worked, but I'm a little confused on the (as the "hello world" Sprite-kit game template syntax) as the sceneDidLoad is the default in the template

Comment: I see, from the looks of it if you choose the "integrate gameplaykit" checkbox it changes to the sceneDidLoad

Comment: Yeah, hope they correct `sceneDidLoad` to the next version.You are not the first programmer that have these problems. Change it to `didMove(to view:` also from the _"integrate gameplaykit"_ template and you will have the same result, this time correctly.